# How can I give a certain row of elements all the same value? Using a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, rows, col

If I have

```
String[][] trenches = new String[10][10];
```

How can i make all elements in row 0 have the value of "X" ?
or all elements in row 1 have the value of "0" ?

Comment: What did you try? That is a very basic task that is trivial to figure out if you tried reading any beginner level book, which everyone shold do before asking a coding question.

Comment: Well, I am a begginer so this "trivial" task seemed daunting to me. Nevertheless, you guys solved it, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a for loop.

```
int row = 0;
int value = 5;

for(int i = 0; i < trenches[row].length(); i ++)
{
    tenches[row][i] = value;
}
```

You could put this in a function and pass the row and value

```
public void standardiseRow(int row, int value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String[][] trenches = new String[10][10];

trenches[0] = StringUtils.repeat("X", 10).split("");
trenches[1] = StringUtils.repeat("0", 10).split("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of your 2d array as an x and y coordinate system. You can have a double for loop that goes through your x multiple times, but goes through your y only one time. In this case, your outer loop would be y and your inner loop would be x.

```
for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        if (y == 0) {             
            array[x][y] = X;
        }
        if (y == 1) {
           array[x][y] = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't want a double loop as this would replace every value in the 2D array and not just the ones in a specified row. The single for loop on the y axis with a preset x axis would be sufficient